# Apscheduler skipping job executions due to maximum number of instances

Tags: python, subprocess, threadpool, python-multithreading, apscheduler

I am trying to use APScheduler to run periodic jobs with an IntervalTrigger, I've intentionally set the maximum number of running instances to one because I don't want jobs to overlap.

Problem is that after some time the scheduler starts reporting that the maximum number of running instance for a job have been reached even after it previously informed that the job finished successfully, I found this on the logs:

```
2015-10-28 22:17:42,137 INFO     Running job "ping (trigger: interval[0:01:00], next run at: 2015-10-28 22:18:42 VET)" (scheduled at 2015-10-28 22:17:42-04:30)
2015-10-28 22:17:44,157 INFO     Job "ping (trigger: interval[0:01:00], next run at: 2015-10-28 22:18:42 VET)" executed successfully

2015-10-28 22:18:42,335 WARNING  Execution of job "ping (trigger: interval[0:01:00], next run at: 2015-10-28 22:18:42 VET)" skipped: maximum number of running instances reached (1)

2015-10-28 22:19:42,171 WARNING  Execution of job "ping (trigger: interval[0:01:00], next run at: 2015-10-28 22:19:42 VET)" skipped: maximum number of running instances reached (1)

2015-10-28 22:20:42,181 WARNING  Execution of job "ping (trigger: interval[0:01:00], next run at: 2015-10-28 22:20:42 VET)" skipped: maximum number of running instances reached (1)

2015-10-28 22:21:42,175 WARNING  Execution of job "ping (trigger: interval[0:01:00], next run at: 2015-10-28 22:21:42 VET)" skipped: maximum number of running instances reached (1)

2015-10-28 22:22:42,205 WARNING  Execution of job "ping (trigger: interval[0:01:00], next run at: 2015-10-28 22:22:42 VET)" skipped: maximum number of running instances reached (1)
```

as you can see on the logs the ping job was reported to be executed successfully but shortly after the next execution is skipped from that point.

this is the code I use to schedule jobs:

```
    executors = {'default': ThreadPoolExecutor(10)}
    jobstores = {'default': SQLAlchemyJobStore(url='sqlite:///jobs.sqlite')}
    self.scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(executors = executors,jobstores=jobstores)
    ...
    self.scheduler.add_job(func=func,
                               trigger=trigger,
                               kwargs=kwargs,
                               id=plan_id,
                               name=name,
                               misfire_grace_time=misfire_grace_time,
                               replace_existing=True)
```

the function itself that is being run starts some threads to execute the ping command over several network nodes and saves the results to a file

```
threads = []
for link in links:
    thread = Thread(target = ping_test, args = (link,count,interval,timeout))
    threads.append(thread)
    thread.start()
for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

notice that the timeout is set to a number much lower than the trigger interval so it's impossible that the job is still executing when the next run triggers.

Any insights on this problem are highly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like the job does NOT finish before the next execution, hence the warning. Have you actually verified that the target callable really finishes before the next run?

Comment: that's a good question but the log shows that the job finished, I even added the thread join mechanism to make sure that no thread was alive before the callable returned but got the same results, how can I check that the target callable actually finishes?

Comment: That log does indeed not make sense. Do you mind increasing the logging level to DEBUG?